# Share one table between two different CMS, possible?

Tags: database, content-management-system

Is there a way to share a user table between two distinct CMSes? If one register in one CMS in a domain it will be registered in other app, other domain automatically.
How two implement such a thing?

Comment: it probably depends on the CMS, actually. So, which CMS('s) are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless there is a plugin developed for that purpose.